# How to implement a new shell command?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to implement my own version of ps command & I am trying to understand how shell commands are implemented in Linux. Is it part of the Shell application or part of the module?

In my understanding, when I type ps in shell prompt: the actual implementation for ps can only reside in kernel & shell just invokes a kernel api/binary.

Now, if I want to add a new command (say myps): what should I modify in shell application? & What should I modify in kernel module?

How shell application knows the list of commands supported in individual modules (kernel, network, fs, etc) ?

Lastly, if (just for example) network module is configured & built only for ipv4 and then there is no point in supporting ipv6 commands in shell? How is this taken care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps` is just a regular program (typically located at /bin/ps). You can find its location on your system by running `which ps`.

When you run a command (assuming it's not a builtin function, alias, etc. implemented by the shell itself), the shell searches the directories listed in your `PATH` environment variable. If you're using sh or bash as your shell, you can see it by running `echo $PATH`. The shell searches the directories in the order they're listed in `PATH`, and runs the first matching program it finds.

If you want to create a new version of `ps`, just write a program and put it in one of the directories on your `PATH`. Typically somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/` (accessible by all users) or `~/bin` (in your home directory). Or you could add a new directory to your `PATH`. No need to mess with the kernel or the shell itself, thankfully.

Comment: Awesome reply !! @user20160